# composer.json specifies dependency, but no composer.lock was found

Tags: git, heroku, composer-php, sendgrid

I have added sendgrid and changed composer.json file in heroku.
composer.json file contains

```
{
    "require": {
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "sendgrid/sendgrid": "2.0.5"
    }
}
```

on commit the file
[image]

When I push into heroku I wiil occurs error as shown in below image

[image]

Comment: run `php composer.phar update` on your local machine and then git add the composer.lock, commit and push again?

Comment: @madebydavid php composer.phar update command not found

Comment: Looks like you need to download it locally too - https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: @madebydavid is it fine if i install coposer-setup.exe. I have made some change please re-look at the quetion.

Comment: Should work, do you have PHP running locally too? You will probably need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installed composer and restart the computer I have used the `composer update` command and then it works fine and error solved

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem too but i don't want to change my local php environment configuration, so i need to use `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` . Otherwise i would need to have same extensions locally as the ones i have in remote heroku.